# Is it posible for a document set to inherit metadata from a document which is inside this document set

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, column, document-set, metadata

I'm running in to this problem where people want to add metadata to a document using that same document.
This is possible using Word quickparts.

Now for the fun part, the documents are inside a 'document set' and the metadata of this 'document set' must be the same as the ones from the document. So instead of the document inheriting from the 'document set' it's the other way around.

I thought it would be as easy as creating a workflow (started manually) to set the field of the current item (this being the document set). But to what value.....? Is there a way to get the metadata of the childitems from a document set..?

I hope i've made myself clear if not please let me know and I try to be more precise.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

What do you actually want by get metadata for document set?

We specify shared metadata in document sets for identifying special properties for documents inside the document set.    And the metadata columns created are for all documents in a set. They are for not for the document set. It is not a inheritance. The document set, like a list, simply provide a column to hold the metadata belongs to documents. We do not have such feature to make a document set have its own metadata.

Default documents are automatically provisioned with the metadata when the Document Set is created, and you can display the shared metadata on the Welcome page.

Comment: You are absolutely right! But apparently it's too much of a hassle to "select the document set and click on 'edit properties'" to add the metadata.

So maybe what I'm actually looking for is an alternative way to add metadata to columns....

Comment: @PaulVermaak, I assume you want to set a default value for the metadata column? You can set it in column settings. What is your desired behavior when trying to add metadata to columns?

Comment: The reasoning of our client is as follows:
We have different applications (1 application = 1 documentset), within this application we have 3 documents and 1 of these documents contains the metadata for the entire application. I've made an table wich might clearify things:
https://ibb.co/84SRtr4
Column 1) The applications (document set)
Column 2) The documents in this set
Column 3&4) the metadata

The users are not familiar with the SP interface that's why they wanted to use WordQuickparts to fill the collumns.
So no there is no default value for the metadata.

Comment: After typing this I start to realise that those users just need to learn some basic SharePoint. We can't create all kind of workarounds so they can use SharePoint without using SharePoint.

@Jerry_MSFT, Thanks for the quick answers!